# W11Ent_x64: restore sequencing file names when downloading pictures from the internet

Tags: browser, windows-11, download

In W7, and maybe W8 was a feature that allowed downloading pictures with the same name, by adding a sequential number attached to it.

Example:

Stellated Dodecahedron in 4D.Gif: when 5 such files were on Google, and you downloaded them, these became automatically:

```
Stellated Dodecahedron in 4D.Gif
Stellated Dodecahedron in 4D(1).Gif
Stellated Dodecahedron in 4D(2).Gif
Stellated Dodecahedron in 4D(3).Gif
Stellated Dodecahedron in 4D(4).Gif
```

How can I restore this automated function?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, this sequencing is a function of the browser
you're using and how that browser handles duplicate file names.

Firefox-based browsers seem not to do any sequencing and just
demand if to replace the file or not.

Chromium-based browsers seem to do sequencing automatically,
although in my tests sometimes the first save with the browser
session may ask to replace, but the following saves will add
the sequencing.

With the fast evolution of browsers, the above behavior may
change without notice at any moment in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, my reply went missing?
Rewriting it:

Thank you for responding, good sir.

Peculiar:
Firefox does not do this, true.
MSEdge, though Chromium in engine, equally so does not do this.
I tried that Chrome thing, ditto.
Even Yandex browser doesn't do this?

Now, File Saving is managed by Windows, I thought?
Considering:
The browser, when asking to save a file, "contacts the File Manager" which does the actual placing of said file, OR SO IT APPEARS, at the very least.
This is "clearly shown" (please note the quote marks) when one wants to save a file from within a browser:
The browser opens, clearly so, what seems to be:
File Explorer?

Am I incorrect, good sir?

If so, I return to my base question.
If not, can you commend a good extension for FF and MSEdge, please?

Thank you.
Ben

Also, how can I stop this site from screwing up my writing format, please?
It's driving me nuts ... .   :(

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My question is the first post.

My secondary post was a repsonce with question towards Mr. HarryMC.

Now, I think, this was quite obvious, good sir.
Isn't it?

If not, please tell me the precise issue, where and in which form my response was .
Severe Asperger's and ADHD, sir ... I do not always get "vague" answers.

Also, this site continues to undo my formatting, how can I stop this, please?